# boto3 module not found

Tags: python, pyspark, boto3

My Pyspark EC2 instance got terminated (my fault) and I am trying to build another one. I have Spark running and now am trying to run a simple Pyspark script to access S3 bucket. The machine has Python 3 installed and I installed boto3 but I get compilation error for the line below.

```
from boto3.session import Session
```

No module named 'boto3' .

Also, I get a logger error saying invalid syntax when I do the following

```
print rddtest.take(10)
```

Not sure what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `compilation error`? I guess you simply try to run the script, not compile it. You need to use `()` with `print()` - your script is probably written in Python2 and you're trying to run it with Python3.

Comment: And how did you install `boto3` module? Try `pip3 install --user boto3`.

Comment: Incorrect choice of words - compilation. Forgot to mention, I did install boto3. sudo apt-get install python-boto3. Thanks for the tip on print.

Comment: Add installed sudo apt-get install python3-boto3.

Answer (score 0):

You might have many python installations in your machine. pip might be installing boto3 for python3.6 while you are currently executing python3.7